# video recording in portrait is coming in 90 degree rotated form in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have develope an app in which i am doing video recording .Every thing is running fine .But when i am recording the video in portrait orientation then video is coming in 90 degree rotated form .

I am using this xaml for video

```
<Rectangle
        x:Name="viewfinderRectangle"
        Width="460"
        Height="661"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
        <MediaElement
        x:Name="VideoPlayer"                  
        Width="460"
        Height="661"
        AutoPlay="True"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10">
                <MediaElement.Projection>
                    <PlaneProjection/>
                </MediaElement.Projection>
            </MediaElement>
```

Comment: You will need to rotate the video.  Verify this still happens if you rotate the actual phone.

Comment: It is coming in rotated form only in portrait orientation. Coming fine in landscape orientaion....

Answer (score 0):

Before start the recording you should use the following property.

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice VideoRecordingDevice;

VideoRecordingDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation,    VideoRecordingDevice.SensorLocation == CameraSensorLocation.Back ? 90 : -90);
```

NB: Remember that it only used for wp8 or later version.